# javascript/jQuery can't find element with messed up id

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm trying to access an element in MS CRM 2011 with the following id:
account|NoRelationship|Form|B_GenerateInvoice-Large

I can see this element in the IE developer tools:
[image]

Unfortunately I always get null when trying to find this element.

I've tried the following:

```
alert(document.getElementById('account|NoRelationship|Form|B_GenerateInvoice-Large'));
alert($("[id='account|NoRelationship|Form|B_GenerateInvoice-Large]").html());
alert($(jq("account|NoRelationship|Form|B_GenerateInvoice-Large")).html());  // jq() adds the '#' and escapes special characters
alert($("#account|NoRelationship|Form|B_GenerateInvoice-Large").html());
alert(document.getElementById("#account\\|NoRelationship\\|Form\\|B_GenerateInvoice-Large"));
alert($("#account\\|NoRelationship\\|Form\\|B_GenerateInvoice-Large").html());
```

These all fail to find the element.

Am I missing something obvious here?

**Solution:**

The javascript was inside an iframe while the element was outside of the iframe..

I did not manage to solve it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [jQuery Manual on Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) states:

> If you wish to use any of the
>   meta-characters ( such as
>   !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a
>   literal part of a name, you must
>   escape the character with two
>   backslashes: \\. For example, if you
>   have an element with id="foo.bar", you
>   can use the selector $("#foo\\.bar").
>   The W3C CSS specification contains the
>   [complete set of rules regarding valid CSS selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier).

So try this one:

```
$('#account\\|NoRelationship\\|Form\\|B_GenerateInvoice-Large')...
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TNZTv/)

**EDIT**: I have successfully tested my Fiddle in Chrome, Firefox 4, IE9, IE8 and IE7, it works fine.

Comment: Good answer @bazmegakapa I didn't know that. I did a little looking around and it looks like there is someone talking about having a selector escape function which seems like a good idea. http://forum.jquery.com/topic/add-a-jquery-selector-escape-function

Comment: the third alert uses a function jq() found on jquery.com which escapes these characters. I tried with your string and I still get a null.

Comment: you can find the escape function here:
http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_select_an_element_by_an_ID_that_has_characters_used_in_CSS_notation.3F

Comment: @Thomas So which browser are you trying with? Have you checked my Fiddle? Did it work?

Comment: your fiddle works in my IE9 so I'm guessing my issue is related to the way MS CRM 2011 is generating its content. I'm going to loop some elements to see if I can find out where it goes wrong.

Comment: @Thomas Is the Javascript code outputted by some server side code, or is it in a simple JS file? Backslashes might have special meaning in the server side code. I don't have any experience with MS CRM, so this is all I can think of :).

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for the `jq()` BTW, didn't know it.

Comment: thanks for the remark, I will investigate. I've just tried finding a parent element way up in the DOM tree and it didnt find anything either.
I can do jQuery ajax calls etc in my piece of code so I'm sure jQuery is working fine.. bleh. I will certainly post here when I find the cause. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @Thomas Are you running the queries in the `$(document).ready()` handler? To be sure the DOM is up at the time you want to find something in it.

Comment: Also thought about that, but this is executed in response to a button click so yeah, the DOM is ready.

Comment: Oh dear lord, apparently CRM 2011 works with an iframe (which is added client-side). I did not spot this and the javascript file seems to be referenced from inside the iframe, while the element that I want to select is outside of the iframe. Sigh.

Comment: Actually I did not manage to solve this. I tried all common javascript and jquery selectors to get the iframe's parent and search from there, but did not succeed after 45 minutes. I have given up and will try an alternative since I dont have budget to keep looking for this, and the feature isn't critical.

Comment: @Thomas You can try posting another question for that.

Comment: @bazmegakapa: Thanks for your continuous interest :-) I managed to get to my element after another 30 minutes of testing. What I needed was: $("#account\\|NoRelationship\\|Form\\|B_GenerateInvoice-Large", window.top.document)

Comment: I had been trying window.top etc, which does not work. bleh :-)

Answer (score 0):

It may be a bug in browser, since HTML5 specification allows any character except spaces in id attribute

> > > ID #
> > >
> > > Any string, with the following restrictions:
> > >
> > > must be at least one character long
> > >
> > > must not contain any space characters

however, it is encrouaged not to put any weired character in id attribute, only number, letter and underscore there:)

Comment: Since HTML 5 is a draft, it can be argued that it isn't a bug, it is just something that hasn't been implemented yet.

Answer (score 0):

From the jQuery documentation:

If you wish to use any of the meta-characters ( such as !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, you must escape the character with two backslashes: \. For example, if you have an element with id="foo.bar", you can use the selector $("#foo\.bar").

So this should work:

```
alert($("#account\\|NoRelationship\\|Form\\|B_GenerateInvoice-Large").html());
```

And it does, indeed: http://jsfiddle.net/Cdz9w/

Comment: Isn't that what @bazmegakapa said?

Comment: @T.J. It exactly is. He was faster.

Comment: thx for the jsfiddle link. This makes me think that the problem is CRM related.

Answer (score 0):

What version of HTML is the page declaring that it's using? Because that's a [valid HTML5 `id`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute), but it's an [invalid HTML4.01 and earlier `id`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name). (It's also an [invalid CSS `id`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier), which is vaguely relevant if you use something like jQuery to look it up, as jQuery uses CSS selectors.)

The fiddle in [@bazmegakapa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122014/javascript-jquery-cant-find-element-with-messed-up-id/6122067#6122067) works for me on Chrome, but perhaps your page is declaring a different version of HTML, or perhaps a less-advanced browser doesn't like it, etc.